# for loop - Error in idx[] <- idx[0] : replacement has length zero

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to create a vector taking into account the two conditions.

```
signal_2=c(0)

for (i in 2: length(price)){
  if (signal[i]==1 & price[i+1] > price[i]){
    signal_2[i]<- 1
  }
    signal_2[i]<- 0
}
```

This function gives me the following error:

```
Error in idx[] <- idx[0] : replacement has length zero
```

Can anyone suggest me how to fix the error or another method to verify the two conditions?

**The conditions are:**
signal in position i == 1 **and**
price in i+1 > price in i

Comment: where's this `idx[]` coming from? Is it part of function?

Comment: no it is not in the function, I don't know what it means.

Comment: What's `idx[]`? And `price[i+1]` is problematic with `for i in 2:length(price)`.

Comment: is `idx[]` part of your code? If so, can you share the complete code? It's very difficult to debug the error, without knowing where it might be occuring

Comment: I don't know what is `idx[]`, it isn't part of my code. Why `price[i+1]` is problematic for the function? Can't it be used? If so, how can I write the same thing in another way?

Comment: *"I don't know what it means."* is a reason to vote to close...

Comment: If `i` is in `2:length(price)`, plus one as in `price[i+1]` will be after the last assigned value of `price`. In R that means a `NA`. Maybe you are looking for `1:(length(price) - 1)`.

Comment: The code seems to want `signal_2 <- c(0L, (signal[-1] == 1) & (diff(price) > 0))`. A fully vectorized one-liner.

Comment: And so how could I rewrite the code? I would verify the condition that compared the price  at the position 3 with respect to that at the position 2, etc.